# Crm Cast Is Not Valid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

There is floating point number field whose name is "new_poscost". The existing value of the field is 0,00 or it can be any decimal value. I want to sum a value with it. But I'm getting a cast error.

In first line of code `poscost` variable is getting the value of attribute. When it comes to assign sum of values to another entity's attribute, I'm getting "cast is not valid" error.

```
decimal poscost = postEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_poscost") ?
      (decimal)postEntity["new_poscost"] : 0m; // value is assigning to poscost properly.

FlightHotel.Entities[0].Attributes["new_poscost"] = poscost+
      (decimal)FlightHotel.Entities[0]["new_poscost"];
```

Comment: Can you safely rule out the error is caused by your `posTutarı` variable? Also I'd suggest to use `decimal poscost = postEntity.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("new_poscost");` which will yield the same result as your version but is a shorter and "cleaner" way.

Comment: it was just copy paste mistake nothing wrong with variable.i checked value of poscost in debug.

Comment: Side note: See [Entity.GetAttributeValue<T> Explained](http://crmentropy.blogspot.de/2013/08/entitygetattributevalue-explained.html) for a nice summary.

Comment: Well since you you can assure the type of `poscost` the next suspect would be `FlightHotel.Entities[0]["new_poscost"]`.

Comment: no difference when i used  Entity.GetAttributeValue<decimal>.And nothing wrong with  FlightHotel.Entities[0]["new_poscost"]

Comment: Are you sure none of your attributes is `Money` rather than decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following approach:

```
double podnost = postEntity.Contains("new_poscost") ? new_poscost.GetAttributeValue<double>("new_poscost") : 0;
```

Comment: You won't need `.Contains` if you're using `.GetAttributeValue<T>` - at least not until you're dealing with EntityReferences.

Comment: ... and it should be `: 0e;`

Comment: And what about OptionSets ;)

Comment: And there is no both compilation or run-time error in code double a = 0; so 0e is not required.

Comment: Of course it's just me nitpicking because the compiler will take care of this ;-) ... and you're right about OptionSets and Money which will blow up with a NullReferenceException if you don't check.

Comment: `Contains` can be used also to define an return a different default value from the one returned by `GetAttributeValue`

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot of that new_poscost field from CRM and code that you have at the moment and which doesn't work?